# Upgrade to TFS 2015.3 successful, but portal unavailable

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Today we have installed update 3 to our existing TFS 2015.2 server. The offline installation ran for about an hour and completed succesfully. However when trying to reach the portal site, nothing shows up (well a 404 page shows up actually).

When opening the Team Foundation Server Administration Console, it correctly displays the expected product version: 14.102.25423.0 (Tfs2015.Update3). However when I click on 'Application Tier', it displays the text:

> This feature has been installed but needs to be configured. Click on
>   Configure Installed Features to begin initial configuration.

This same text is shown on many other administrative pages. Is this the cause of the portal missing? When I configure these features again, will it not erase our current team projects, history, build definitions and work items?

Are there any better ways to troubleshoot why the portal is missing?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. After the upgrade, the configuration is needed to make sure the normal operation of TFS server. **It will not erase your current team projects, history, build definitions and work items.** There are just some settings will not effect your Database. Certainly, it's also important to keep good backup habits. After all, we didn't have a foolproof thing in the world.

> After you upgrade TFS to 2015, each team project may need to be
> configured to use some of the new features in TFS 2015. You don't have
> to do this immediately, but those features aren't available in that
> team project until they're configured. Depending on the team project,
> you'll use some combination of the Configure Features wizard that
> appears on the Work page and some manual configuration.
>
> Source Link: [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/upgrade-tfs/get-started)

For your situation, there maybe some other error cause it. However, still suggest you to finish the configuration first. If it's still not work, then you can try below ways to narrow down the issue:

- Check the **Event View** in the server to see whether there are some
  related info
- Check the **configuration logs** (Team Foundation Server Administration
  Console-Logs or browser the folder in  the  server
  `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs`)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. We have completed the upgrade configuration process. It works again perfectly now!